# How to keep activity running in background?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

Most of you must have used "whatsapp" and "viber". These apps constantly keep running even when they are exited. I want one of my activities to keep running in the background after its being ran for the first time. And I also want the whole app to keep running in the background like viber and whatsapp do.  How can I do that?

Comment: You need to create a service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Movetasktoback(true); ... use this

Answer (score 3):

Use `service`. Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) about details of service.

You can keep your activity running in the background. But I think it is definitely a better idea to keep a service running in the background. You will get a basic idea about the service by reading above two links.

Comment: I'm using a 3rd-party which I don't have control and only works with an activity but not a service. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

It's not the `Activity` that keeps running in the background but a `Service`. Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for implementing it.