# Android: How to attach a Service in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, service

> **I am developing a simplle Android Application to play an .mp3 file from device storage by giving the path. I need to play that mp3 file
>   from Background and show a notification by song title...**

How i can use a Service and play music in bakground by displaying song title..

The code I used is ...

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button start,pause,stop;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        //creating media player
        final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();
        try{
            //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp3");

            mp.prepare();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
        pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.pause();
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to find the code .. ThankYou ....

Comment: Did you try to run it? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: the programs works fine. but when i used another app in front the music stops playing.

Comment: you need to resume and ondestroyed method to this.. playing on resume you need to prepare...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at [this](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/simple-android-foreground-service-example/) to get the idea.

Comment: This must be a comment !

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209858/android-background-music-service) or [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/Playmp3filewithinaservice.htm)

And make sure to register service in your manifest file

Comment: This must be a comment !

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a service for running your activity in background?

Maybe this could help you:

[How to keep activity running in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510462/how-to-keep-activity-running-in-background)

Comment: Sorry @AndroidDeveloperTrainee. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   try {
                mp = new MediaPlayer();

               mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Jithin's/downloadedfile.mp3");
                mp.setLooping(false); // Set looping
                mp.setVolume(100,100);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }





@Override
protected void onResume() {

        try {

                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

            mp.stop();

    }
}
```

Note: You sure the Path exist... so when you start music or stop check path is exist than play