# How I can have an activity running in the background?

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, background

I'm working in a project in which we need to load an Activity with a WebView, we need to load some HTML with Angular but we need to have this activity in the background until this activity/webview with angular has loaded finally.

Is there any way to do this with an activity?

Comment: check this [How to keep activity running in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16510462/7666442)

Answer (score 1):

When an `Activity` goes to background, it is not running anymore. You can do background tasks with `Service`, but not `Activity`. You can work on `onResume()` method of your `Activity` with the webview when angular has loaded your required information.

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` is most of the time inside an `Activity`. So the `Activity`, where the `WebView` is, will always be there until you kill it. Unless you really want the `Activity` to be really running on the background, then use a `Service` instead.

Because you might need to use a `Service` for what you want, then I guess you need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` inside the `Service`. Inside the `BroadcastReceiver`, you have a custom tag that when called using a `sendBroadcast()` will `startActivity()` your webview/activity. I don't guarantee the speed of the loading for the `WebView` because you mentioned that you want to preload the page but that'll do it. To lessen the load time for the `WebView`, you must enable caching on the `WebView`.

Another problem that I'm thinking that would happen if you really want to hold a `WebView` on the background (if you can even do that) is memory leak. Because you want to keep the `WebView` alive at all times even if it isn't even shown on the screen, you'll probably don't want it to be garbage collected which will be a really bad problem on android devices with low memory. You won't get it often on devices with lots of memory but not of 300mb devices.

Comment: How I can use a Service to load the WebView?? How I can show the webview in anywhere of the app?

Comment: Oh, so that's what you want to do. Can you share why you need to show the webview anywhere on the app? Is it like an advertisement? It'll help me think of some other way we could accomplish what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, I need a webview ready all the time for the execution of some angular methods at anytime in any activity/fragment

Comment: What do you need to do with the results of the method?